# INVALID_FUNCTION error when writing to HID file

Tags: c++, hid

I am writing a program to send data to an HID device. I followed the following page from Microsoft's documentation: [Finding and Opening a HID Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/finding-and-opening-a-hid-collection) and I get the file handle successfully, but when I try to write using WriteFile, I get an INVALID_FUNCTION error (1). I have sent the same data to the device through a Hyperterminal and it worked, so I'm sure that the information I am sending is correct.
Here is my code:

```
HANDLE m_hCommPort;
GUID guid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE;
HDEVINFO hinfo;
DWORD index = 0;
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData;
BOOL result;
PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetailData = NULL;
DWORD requiredSize;
DWORD deviceIndex = 0;

hinfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);

deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
result = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hinfo, NULL, &guid, deviceIndex, &deviceInterfaceData);
while (result == TRUE) {
    deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);
    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hinfo, &deviceInterfaceData, NULL, 0, &requiredSize, &deviceInfoData);
    deviceInterfaceDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)malloc(requiredSize);
    deviceInterfaceDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);
    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hinfo, &deviceInterfaceData, deviceInterfaceDetailData, requiredSize, NULL, &deviceInfoData);
    Trace(TEXT(deviceInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath));
    if (_tcsstr(deviceInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath, "vid_0c2e&pid_0be7")) {
        Trace(TEXT(deviceInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath));
        break;
    }
    result = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hinfo, NULL, &guid, ++deviceIndex, &deviceInterfaceData);
}
if (result == FALSE) {
    ErrorExit("SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces ");
}
else if(deviceInterfaceDetailData != NULL){
    m_hCommPort = CreateFile(deviceInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    if (m_hCommPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        ErrorExit("CreateFile");
    }
    else {
        DWORD bytesWritten;
        char scanCommand[] = { 22,77,13,'I','M','G','S','N','P','1','B' };
        DWORD size = sizeof(scanCommand);
        BOOL fileWritten = WriteFile(m_hCommPort, scanCommand, size, &bytesWritten, NULL);
        if (fileWritten == TRUE) {
            Trace(TEXT("Wrote %d files to device"), bytesWritten);
        }
        else {
            ErrorExit("Error writing to file");
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to understand why I am getting this error please?

Comment: Where is the `GetLastError()` call that's giving you the 1?

Comment: It is inside the ErrorExit function, as defined in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The one that is giving the 1 is the last call to ErrorExit (just below the WriteFile call).

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution?